# Android minLines and maxLines aren't working together in same TextView

Tags: android, listview, textview

Here I have only 1 item in `ListView` and I'm showing two different `TextViews` of different colors at the end of the `ListView` item.

But the issue is I wanna show maximum 3 lines of each `TextView` but it's not providing me a good result if length of `TextView` is small. But it works well if text is large.

When I add `android:maxLines="3"` and text is small, it destroys my layout like

And when I add `android:minLines="2"` and text is large, it shows complete text like

Give me a way to overcome this problem. My each `TextView` looks like:

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_previous_story"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/privacy_text_size" />
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue where if I set min and max it only ever makes it min line length.  Have you found a fix?

Comment: show me your UI please

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the number of lines ex: 3 just use android:lines="3" in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_width="match_parent"`,

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_previous_story"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size" />
```

OR

```
tv_previous_story.setMaxLines(3);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work and it took some extra space also

Comment: what is problem in textview now ?@Anshul

Comment: it took extra space in 3rd line if text is small and I don't want that.

Comment: remove android:lines="3" and check @Anshul

Answer (score -2):

If you want to fix the TextView text use :

```
android:ems="10"
```

or any value you want in place of 10.
`android:ems` or `setEms(n)` sets the width of a TextView to fit a text of n 'M' letters regardless of the actual text extension and text size.