# How to make TextView have maxLines and if it doesn't fit expand horizontally?

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-textview-autosize

I don't want to use scrollView.The behavior I want is this:

Short Text:

[image]

Long text:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried minLines in XML?

something like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_previous_story"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:minLines="2" //(could be any minimum amount of lines)
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/privacy_text_size" />
```

this should work fine for you if you always have at least two words (or the minimal amount of lines you've set in the XML)...

If this isn't what you search for, maybe you could handle it programmatically and set the width and height of the TextView according to the number of words... not the exact method, but for example:

```
void updateWidthAndHeightOfTextView(TextView tv, String t) {
   tv.setWidth(t.length * [bla bla bla]);
   tv.setHeight(tv.getWidth() / [bla bla bla]); //(if you want to change the height too, in this case according to the width)
}
```

You write it your way, you know your needs...

And, there's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35195717/8099601) answer, that I'm actually not familiar with but might also answer your needs...

### **UPDATE**

In case I didn't understand when I wrote the above and you want the `TextView` to have maxLines and only dynamic width, you could use the `tv.setWidth(t.length * [bla bla bla]);` in the semi method that I wrote above, and in the .XML use maxLines...

Also, next time please give a bit more specific questions so people won't have to struggle to try to understand how to give you the relevant answer to what you want.

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="Your text here"
    android:textColor="@color/purple_500"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:lines="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="16sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

For short text your output be like:

[image: Short Text Image]

For long text:

[image: Long Text Image]